# looking for a training script of resnet for cifar10 in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, resnet

I want to find a training script for resnet on cifar10 in tensorflow.
I have checked the code in estimator and slim. But both are not suitable for my project.

I need the following:

1. a good training script that can reach 93% accuracy. II find that training script of resnet on cifar10 in estimator is good. The key is the learning rate. But estimator API is fixed.
2. I need to modify the model architecture, replace some ops in the model.
3. control the input data, so that I can replace cifar10 with other datasets such as SVHN.
4. After training, I need to analyze the output logit of each input image in the train and test set.

Testing a new script need several days on my computer. I don't want to write the script from scratch. It is so expensive for me.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

This script from tensorpack examples might work for you: https://github.com/tensorpack/tensorpack/blob/master/examples/ResNet/cifar10-resnet.py

1. It reaches 93%+ cifar10 accuracy.
2. The architecture is in the same file (single file) so you can modify.
3. You can switch to the SVHN dataset easily following [another example](https://github.com/tensorpack/tensorpack/blob/master/examples/basics/svhn-digit-convnet.py) or write your own dataloader for your own dataset.
4. Getting the logits takes [several lines of code](https://tensorpack.readthedocs.io/tutorial/inference.html#offlinepredictor).